# XAML FlowDocument with multiple Paragraph's from list of strings (Binding)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, flowdocument

I need to display list of objects in FlowDocument. I don't want to add it programmatically, but want to pass this list of objects via binding. For example:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>        
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Text}" />
                    </Paragraph>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>        
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

There list of objects contains simple object like:

```
public class Line
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Best regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the code below:**

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument> 
<BlockUIContainer>
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Lines}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
                   
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</BlockUIContainer>
</FlowDocument>  
</RichTextBox>
```

**Lines should be of type IEnumerable/ObservableCollection.**

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and compiler says "XLS0503 A value of type 'ListView' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'BlockCollection'"

Comment: yes there is some problem in compilation. You can use </BlockUIContainer> tag inside FlowDocument. It will resolve the issue hopefully.

Comment: Unfortunately </BlockUIContainer> didn't help. But found a workaround :). Thanks for your help! 